# Picture scroller broken, Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, slider, posts, jslider

The theme I am using has a "custom modified Nivo Slider for Featured posts." It was functioning perfectly until this afternoon when I noticed the effects are lingering on the photos with vertical lines running down them. I can't determine what set this off. I only added a few pages to the nav menu. I didn't install any plugins, touch the styling or functionality of the site at all.

Curious if anyone has seen this before and could lend a hand. I am happy to Paste Bin any of the code that you would need to see. Here is the link to the site: http://mefo1.ecin1prod1lnx1.com/

Best regards,

Alex

Comment: If it helps at all, I cannot see what you are talking about. The slider viewed on OS X, FF4 seems to work just fine for me. I wonder if it might be related to your internet connection.

Comment: Same here. The slider works fine in OSX on Chrome 11

Comment: Very strange, it is fine for me now as well. Thank you @Sardine and @Chris_O

Answer (score 1):

The width of the image must be able to be divided by the number of slices without leaving any fractions. ie a 672 pixel wide image can be divided into 14 slices (of exactly 48 pixels each), but not by 15 slices (of 44.8pixels each). Worked perfectly for me.
I found the solution here: https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider/issues/114

Also be sure that your images conform to the pixel width of the slider images in the css. I downloaded a theme with css set to:

```
#slider {
    width:672px;
    height:374px !important;
```

but the images that came with the template were of varying widths eg 670px and 674px as well as varying heights. So I had to readjust them all to the 672x374px.

If you do both this and the slice calculation above, you should have no problems.